# Trying to Create a Site Map but Words Appear On Separate Lines

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on developing a site map for my website. The intent is to have it as a fixed bar that spans the bottom of every page. I'm using https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/half-slider/ as the source of my Bootstrap template. However, when I try to add words to my site map, every single word ends up on its own line. Currently, I have the following:

CSS:

```
footer>.container>.row>.col-lg-12 {
margin: 0 -9999rem;
padding: 0.25rem 9999rem;
position: fixed;
background-color: black;
color: white;
bottom: 0
}
```

HTML:

```
<footer>
    <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-12">
                 <p>Contact Us</p>
                 <p>Find Out More</p>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

just break them into more dives like below or do p class="col-lg-4"

```
  <footer>
   <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                     <p>Contact Us</p>
                </div>
               <div class="col-lg-4">
                     <p>Find Out More</p>
                </div>

             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
</footer>
```

or

```
<footer>
  <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-12">

                 <p class="col-lg-4">Contact Us</p>                              
                 <p class="col-lg-4">Find Out More</p>                
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
</footer>
```

check out https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar for another example

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't change anything. Am I supposed to be changing something in the CSS as well?

Comment: look here for documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/ you may have your template which wraps bootstrap overwriting some of the bootstrap built in cssor look here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar

Comment: What I'm noticing is that when I resize my page and make it smaller, the elements actually go to being on the lines they're supposed to be on. So somehow, the box they are stored in when the screen is at full size is tall and skinny but when I make the screen smaller, the box becomes longer and is able to hold "contact us" all on one line.

Answer (score 0):

Paragraphs are automatically styled to be `display:block;` which makes them appear on different lines. Make your p `display:inline-block;` and then it should work.

Comment: Better ways to do this without setting global styles. The answer below is the best way to do it with Bootstrap.